# UITextContainerView not resizing as his UITextView superview, only when rotated with an angle grater than 45°

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView that resizes with pinch and rotation gestures simultaneously.
To resize it, I call the function textViewDidChange() in the pinch gesture handler function, while the sender state is of type .changed and after increasing the font size of the Text View.

Here is the function:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = textView.bounds

    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    textView.bounds = newFrame

}
```

The problem is that when I rotate the Text View at an angle grater than 45 degrees, the text of the Text View is cropping. Using the Debug View Hierarchy, I noticed that the UITextContainerView of the Text View has a smaller width than its superview.

[Debug View Hierarchy screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxYxJ.png) The red rectangle is the Text View and the highlighted one is its UITextContainerView.

The Text View is resizing correctly, but the UITextContainerView is not.
I don't understand why this is happening, anyone can help me?

[There was a link to a YouTube video but it has been deleted so the link was removed.]

Comment: Can you screen record it?

Comment: @Farhad I've just added a screen record example

Answer (score 1):

Disable Scrolling on the textView.
This would automatically increase the height of the textView according to the contentSize.

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Comment: I've already done it. The textView is added to the view by code, not using the Storyboard, with isScrollEnabled = false.
I think that the problem is with the width and not the height, I've also tried to set the contentSize equals to the size of the textView and then use layoutIfNeeded(), but with no result.

Comment: Yes, you have to specify the right frame to place you textView i.e the Origin and Size. And then setting isScrollEnabled = false will do the work. you don’t need to do anything else for eg: adjusting the height in textViewDidChange delegate method.Also you don’t have to make changes to the textView’s width , you have to adjust the height using the textView.textContainer.contentHeight

Comment: Can you make a little example, please? I have that problem with only the rotation. Adding new lines increases the height correctly and using the pinch gesture resizes the textView as I wanted (to increase the width and height linearly to fit the new font size and not to increase only the height)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, it occurs when I update height constraint of textview after an other view hide. And I use

```
    self.viewSearchResults.isHidden = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        self.constraintTextViewsHeight.constant = 100
    }
```

and problem is fixed.